# SSH to remote machine, grep output, close connection

Tags: linux, ssh, grep

I am trying to execute a command on a remote machine, grep the output, put it in a file and then close the connection.
This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p ***** ssh user@remotemachine | grep 'TEXT' > output.txt
```

The script is stops and there is no output in output.txt

Any ideas how I can script this?

Comment: Where is your command ? I see only grep after pipe

Comment: The command is grep, i only want to grep the output after the SSH session. When i log in into the remote machine, the info i need is display by default after login, so i do a grep on the text i want and i want to put that into a text file and close the ssh connection.

Comment: @bana123, no, this is not how you use these tools. Your SSH needs to run a command. That command's output becomes the input to the `grep` command, if you're using a pipe to connect them. Alternately, you need to remove the pipe if you want to execute the `grep` on the remote machine and have it look directly at some (currently unspecified) input file.

Comment: Also, consider using keys instead of `sshpass`.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p ***** ssh user@remotemachine " grep 'TEXT' > output.txt"
```

in your shell script,you just use ssh login in your remove server,and after executing  `ssh` command,then run `grep` in you **local machine**,so ,you get nothing

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Your command is the same as mine, posted above.

Comment: have you try my script,perhaps you could try before you post comment:)

Comment: I get the follow error:

`buffer_get_ret: trying to get more bytes 4 than in buffer 0
buffer_get_int: buffer error`

Comment: it seems something wrong with sshd,perhaps it is something wrong about your `authorized_keys` or `known_host`,maybe you could check it again